# std::thread context of execution (c++14)

Tags: multithreading, pointers, c++11, c++14, stdthread

The problem appear when an in/out variable of a function called by std::thread changes the value during the execution...

---

*Function:*

```
static int func(stThread_t *&pStThread)
```

---

*Parameters*

pStThread: It´s a struct that has a pointer to std::thread and other variables (some flags)

```
typedef struct stThread {
   stThread() noexcept {...};    
   stThread(const stThread &cRigth) noexcept {...};    
   stThread & operator = (const stThread &cRigth) noexcept {...};

   std::thread *pThread;
   volatile bool bBegin;
   volatile bool bEnd;

 } stThread_t;
```

The function **func** print the address of the std::thread of the parameter 
pStThread and the thread id

> func before 1785280 this_id 21968

after making an this_thread::sleep for 2 seconds, it print it again

> func afer ... this_id 21968

```
   static int func(stThread_t *&pStThread) {

      std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();

      long long p_begin = (long long)pStThread;
      std::cout << "func before " << std::to_string(p_begin) << " this_id " << this_id << "\n";
      std::cout.flush();

      pStThread->bBegin = true;

      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));

      this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
      long long p_end = (long long)pStThread;
      std::cout << "func afer " << std::to_string(p_end) << " this_id " << this_id << "\n";
      std::cout.flush();

      pStThread->bEnd = true;

      return 1;
   };
```

The address of the pointer to std::thread it´s changed (corrutped, deleted..?)

---

The pStThread is pushing_back of a list of pointer struct stThread_t

```
std::list<stThread_t*> listOfThreads;
listOfThreads.push_back(pStThread);
```

I read about std::move, but does not work with pointers

---

At the end there is a thread "garbage collector" that it is trying to erase all the threads pending of execution.

---

Full code here

```
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>

#include <iostream>

typedef struct stThread {
   stThread() noexcept {
      pThread = NULL;
      bBegin = false;
      bEnd = false;
   };

   stThread(const stThread &cRigth) noexcept {
      this->pThread = cRigth.pThread;
      this->bBegin = (bool)cRigth.bBegin;
      this->bEnd = (bool)cRigth.bEnd;
   };

   stThread & operator = (const stThread &cRigth) noexcept {
      this->pThread = cRigth.pThread;
      this->bBegin = (bool)cRigth.bBegin;
      this->bEnd = (bool)cRigth.bEnd;

      return *this;
   };

   std::thread *pThread;
   volatile bool bBegin;
   volatile bool bEnd;

} stThread_t;

class CMain
{
public:
   typedef std::list<stThread_t*> MyList_threads;
   MyList_threads listOfThreads;

public:
   CMain() {

      std::cout << std::boolalpha << "Ex1 is move-constructible? "
         << std::is_move_constructible<stThread_t>::value << '\n'
         << "Ex1 is trivially move-constructible? "
         << std::is_trivially_move_constructible<stThread_t>::value << '\n'
         << "Ex1 is nothrow move-constructible? "
         << std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<stThread_t>::value << '\n'
         << "Ex2 is trivially move-constructible? "
         << std::is_trivially_move_constructible<stThread_t>::value << '\n'
         << "Ex2 is nothrow move-constructible? "
         << std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<stThread_t>::value << '\n';
   };

   static int func(stThread_t *&pStThread) {

      std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();

      long long p_begin = (long long)pStThread;
      std::cout << "func before " << std::to_string(p_begin) << " this_id " << this_id << "\n";
      std::cout.flush();

      pStThread->bBegin = true;

      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));

      this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
      long long p_end = (long long)pStThread;
      std::cout << "func afer " << std::to_string(p_end) << " this_id " << this_id << "\n";
      std::cout.flush();

      pStThread->bEnd = true;

      return 1;
   };

   int _createThreads() {
      for (int iIdx = 0; (iIdx < 5); iIdx++) {
         stThread_t *pStThread = new stThread_t;

         pStThread->pThread = new std::thread(&CMain::func,
            std::ref(pStThread));

         if (pStThread) {
            do {
               std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
            } while (!pStThread->bBegin);
            listOfThreads.push_back(pStThread);

            std::string sLog;
            sLog = "\nlistOfThreads.push_back " + std::to_string((long long)pStThread) + "\n";
            std::cout << sLog;
            std::cout.flush();
         }

         std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
      }
      return 1;
   };

   int _main() {

      _createThreads();

      std::thread thread_collector([=]() {
         bool bEnd = false;
         MyList_threads::iterator it;
         it = listOfThreads.end();

         do {
            stThread_t *pStThread = NULL;

            if (it == listOfThreads.end()) {
               it = listOfThreads.begin();
               if (it == listOfThreads.end()) bEnd = true;
            }
            else it++;

            if (it != listOfThreads.end()) {
               if ((*it)->bEnd) {
                  pStThread = *it;

                  listOfThreads.erase(it);
                  it = listOfThreads.begin();
               }
            }

            if (pStThread) {
               if (pStThread->pThread) {
                  if (pStThread->pThread->joinable()) {
                     pStThread->pThread->join();

                     std::cout << " element deleted  " << std::to_string((long long)pStThread) << "\n";
                     std::cout.flush();
                  }
                  delete pStThread->pThread;
                  pStThread->pThread = NULL;
               }
               delete pStThread;
            }
            pStThread = NULL;


            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));

         } while (!bEnd);
      });



      if (thread_collector.joinable()) {
         thread_collector.join();
      }

      return 1;
   };
};

int main()
{
   CMain _main;
   _main._main();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: That would be great if you could shorten your code and indicate the problematic areas.

Comment: `volatile bool` is not thread safe; you want `std::atomic_bool`, aka `std::atomic<bool>`.

Comment: if you use std::thread you can use ThreadSanitizer with recent clang and gcc

Comment: Another minor note: `_createThreads` is not a legal identifier for the user to use in the global namespace scope; identifiers beginning with an underscore followed by a lower-case letter are reserved. There are some other classes of reserved identifiers too; the safe thing is to use a single *trailing* underscore, rather than a *leading* one. This sounds like a pedantic nitpick, but sometimes you get name collisions, and they can sometimes lead to extremely obscure problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a rather straightforward bug, that is mostly unrelated to threading:

(1) `func` takes a *reference* to an `stThread_t*`.

```
static int func(stThread_t *&pStThread);
```

(2) You pass in a reference to `pStThread`

```
std::thread(&CMain::func,std::ref(pStThread));
```

(3) Which is a local variable whose lifetime ends as soon as the loop iteration is finished

```
  for (int iIdx = 0; (iIdx < 5); iIdx++) {
     stThread_t *pStThread = new stThread_t;
     //...
  }
```

(4) And consequently, you get undefined behavior when your function tries to access the object after it is destroyed. (be careful! here, "the object" refers to the *pointer* in question, not the object the pointer is pointing to)

It's unclear why you insist on passing `pStThread` by reference; your function doesn't actually modify the pointer (just what's pointed to), and you don't seem to intend to do any of the things that such a device is actually good for.

Comment: (2) If I change for this         `pStThread->pThread = new std::thread(&CMain::func,
            //std::ref(pStThread) 
            pStThread); ` the compiler says:         
`1>D:\Archivos de programa (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\thr/xthread(238): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'`

Comment: changing `static int func(stThread_t *pStThread) {` work fine !! thank  you!